# Why (not how) must an Object conform to the javadoc of equals()?

Tags: java, equals

[The javadoc of `Object.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) explains the rules you need to follow to correctly override the method.  It says:

1. It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
2. It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
3. It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
4. It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
5. For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

If someone asked me why `equals()` should follow these rules the only answer I could give is, "Because the javadoc says so".  I'm not satisfied with that.  I'd like to have a deeper understanding of **why** these rules exist.  Can someone go through each of these rules and explain, by example, what would go wrong if they were violated?

Comment: This is a strange question. It's so that you always know what you're getting when you call `.equals()` on an Object. Without a set of rules, you wouldn't really know what `.equals()` was giving you. But that seems fairly obvious, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are mathematical definitions of how equality works.  I would refer to mathematics as the deeper reasons.

Joshua Bloch, the designer of the Collections API, spelled these out in his "Effective Java".  I'd recommend that you read that chapter and all the others.

You can find chapter 3 [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=effective%20java%20chapter%203&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.scribd.com/doc/36454091/Effective-Java-Chapter3&ei=eOaDUfXoG4e09gS0xoCQCw&usg=AFQjCNH0Ze02moVLfnaq_T37ukhIS5NSRQ&sig2=ZPmvi1x-seaTOmEC69H3nQ&bvm=bv.45960087,d.eWU).

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is that there are many classes and APIs that depend on the correct functionality of `equals` to work properly. The most common use is in the `java.util` package, `List`s and `Set`s and `Map`s and so forth, but there are many, many others.

By having a robust definition of `equals`, you enable functionality for things like sorting, etc. Instead of giving you a "reason", which is kind of hard to do, I'll give you an example for each.

- **Reflexive:** If you tried to put the same element in a `Set` twice, it would be in the set twice, preventing the no-duplicates functionality from working.
- **Symmetric:** Sorting functionality would be very unpredictable.
- **Transitive:** Again, sorting functionality.
- **Consistent:** Everything would be woefully unpredictable.
- **Null:** Insertions would make little sense in things such as `Set`s and `Map`s

For more information, I invite you to check out the [Wikipedia entry on Equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29)

Answer (score 2):

**Requirement**

> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.

**Explanation**

This is saying that an object, X, should always return true when compared with itself. That logically follows. Think about the '=' operator.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
if(x == x) { // We expect this to be true every time }
```

---

**Requirement**

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

**Explanation**

Well, this is a property of the `=` in mathematics. Look at it like this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
if(x == y) { // This should return true }
if(y == x) { // We expect this to have the same output as the first if }
```

---

**Requirement**

> It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.

**Explanation**

Again, some code can explain why.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 1;

if(y == x && x == z)
{
   // It only logically follows that y == z.
}
```

---

**Requirement**

> It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.

**Explanation**

This one is kind of self explanatory. All it says is that it behaves like a mathematical function. That is, for the same input, it will yield the same output every time.

---

**Requirement**

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

**Explanation**

This is simply a standard that was agreed. But also, holds up logically. To successfully call the `equals` method of an object, it must be `non-null`. If it is `non-null`, and you're testing for equality against `null`, it has to be unequal, hence `false`.

Comment: My code did have a mistake in it, but what you've suggested is unnecessary. If x and y are the same value, and y and z are the same value, then x and z are the same value.

Comment: No. I'm showing you why, logically, equals should have those criteria. It makes it behave, most like an `=` in mathematics. The code was simply to illustrate the logic.

Comment: Well regardless, I don't feel like I have a deeper understanding from this.  I was looking for answers like I found in Effective Java linked by @duffymo that say things like "The first requirement says merely that an object must be equal to itself. It is hard to imagine violating this requirement unintentionally. If you were to violate it and then add an instance of your class to a collection, the collection’s contains method would almost certainly say that the collection did not contain the instance that you just added." That's a **why**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking philosophically why we should follow any rules with a given virtual method of an API, the answer is that **every piece of software is destined to exist in a huge ecosystem** and it's a lot more practical if some guidelines are defined for the interactions within that ecosystem. If that weren't the case, we'd be facing a nightmare of compatibility, maintenance and progress.

If your question is really specific to the `equals()` method and nothing else, well... Most of the properties required of the overrides of this method **are derived from how we use equality in mathematics and logic**. I can't name off the top of my head a useful system where these properties don't apply. So, the reasons are familiarity and predictability.

> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
>   should return true.

This is pretty much the **essence** of the `equals()` method. If this didn't apply, the method wouldn't have a purpose - or, at least, it should have another name.

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

We'd have to depart from a very familiar and deeply rooted way of thinking to program in Java if `x equals y` wasn't an equivalent statement to `y equals x`. **These two expressions are supposed to do the same checks** regardless of order, otherwise they don't indicate true equality, but something else (a partial equality of some sort).

> It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.

If this wasn't true, it would mean that `equals()` does more than compare the states of two objects in a determined way. Maybe it involves **non-deterministic behavior** or maybe it considers the **state of another object or the program state** in the comparison, which would make it very unpredictable and a lot less useful than it is.

> It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.

If this weren't true, it would mean that `equals()` (by definition of not complying with the above) involves something **non-deterministic**. There is no reason I can think of why one would want non-deterministic behavior *in comparisons*.

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

This is a **convention** that makes sense intuitively. Comparison of an object to `null` happens frequently, so this case has the behavior that's most useful for that occasion. If we couldn't differentiate an live object from `null`, we'd have to end up with some very awkward code patterns instead.